# SOAP Fault ; unable to handle

Tags: php, soap, complextype, soapfault

I've got error: Unable to handle request without a valid action parameter.
I want to just login by SOAP server.
My wsdl is here: https://demo.krd.pl/Siddin/2.1/Import.asmx?WSDL
and my code is like:

```
$client = new SoapClient('https://demo.krd.pl/Siddin/2.1/Import.asmx?WSDL', array(
            'location' => 'https://demo.krd.pl/Siddin/2.1/Import.asmx?WSDL',
            'trace' => 1,
            'exceptions' => true,
            'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
            'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS,
            'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2
        ));
    $auth = new stdClass();
    $auth->UserName = 'aaa';
    $auth->Password = 'bbb';
    $auth = new SoapVar($auth, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 'complexType', null, 'LoginRequest', 'types');
    $result = $client->login($auth);
    die(var_dump($result));
```

As You can see, I want to invoke method 'login' on this SOAP server with parameter LoginRequest - it's described in wsdl file. How do that?

Comment: rafaluf - I'm not a PHPian, but if you describe it more. I can definitely hel you on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
without a valid action parameter.
```

This means that your php soap client is not able to make up the needed SOAPAction http header. You WSDL defines for login method this:

```
soapAction="http://Siddin.ServiceContracts/2006/09/Login"
```

There are a number of reasons possible for it not to add the header, e.g. this one:

```
'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
```

Try changing it to

```
'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
```

In case that doesnt resolve it, i recommend you to start general soap debugging by tracing the message being sent (including http headers) and compare it to a working request that you can set up e.g. using SoapUI https://www.soapui.org/

Comment: But this program doesnt give tell me what PHP code I should write this only provides me valid XML...I am interest valid PHP CODE!

Comment: Not Sure what you mean, do  you want to say stackoverflow Users to write your code?

Comment: This program produced to me this XML :<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://Siddin.ServiceContracts/2006/09">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:LoginRequest>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ns:UserName>aaa</ns:UserName>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ns:Password>bbb</ns:Password>
      </ns:LoginRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>   but now I want to create PHP code which will produce this XML in sending to SOAP server. i want to know, where I am wrong in my PHP code.